# Does Flink task managers ever talk to the deep store service?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, distributed-system

I am interested in understanding how Flink performs checkpoints (or savepoints) a little better. Here is my points of curiosity:

Does Flink Job manager gather all the state from the task managers and then push this data to the deep store service (like GCP or S3)? Or, does each of the task managers and job managers push state independent of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall the design is that each task manager writes the state it is managing, and the job manager writes the metadata. Each of these machines (or containers) writes directly to the distributed filesystem, and they all need to use the same URI.

However, the details are a little more complex. A checkpoint (or savepoint) consists of many files, with each state chunk being written into its own file. Except that any state chunks smaller than `state.backend.fs.memory-threshold` are collected by the job manager and written inline into the metadata. This helps to avoid writing lots of small files, which can be a problem with object stores such as S3.

Comment: Do you mean the task managers write to GCS (or S3) directly? Or do you mean that this is written to local disk and then the Job manager picks up the data and sends it over to GCS (or S3)?

I am interested in finding out if I need to create network rules to allow task managers to talk to GCS (and S3), or, is it enough to only let the job manager talk to GCS (and S3).

Comment: Each task manager (and the job manager) writes directly to GCS (or S3). Relaying all of the data through the JM would be too much of a bottleneck. Only the small state chunks are relayed through the JM so that it can coordinate writing all of them into the metadata.